# What is the best way to create parametrized "components" in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

### The initial question

My question can be easily misunderstood, so I will use an example, or better, I will make a  comparison.

Consider ASP.NET web applications. There it is possible to define `ascx` components. Those components are quite nice because they define pieces of reusable code with some more intelligent features that make them not just pieces of plain code... but parametrized parts for a web application.

My question is, of course considering that Node.js is not ASP.NET: what is the most similar solution in Node.js to define reusable components (parametrized)?

Thankyou

#### For those not familiar with ASP.NET

I am aware that not everyone might be familiar with ASP.NET. So I am going to detail a little bit more what I need here. Passing parameters to an html or jade segmente of code is something I can do in Node.js, but what I would like to do is writing my jade/html code into a file (it contains some divs and something else), and then reference it inside another jade/html document or one parameter passed inside it.

### The new revised question

When I was told to use mixins in order to solve this issue, I started looking for them and also tried some, it was ok, I managed getting the simplest mixins done, but when I had to make things a little more complex, mixins started behaving strangely. So now I am wondering about whether they are the solution I have been looking for. So now I am going to explain in details what I want to achieve (as I was too generic).

I have a web page written using `Jade` and I need to create a component that I can reuse throughout my page. This component is just a structured div that will contain an article. If I were to write this component in pseudo-code, this is what it would probably look like in `Jade`ish syntax:

```
component article(@title, @subtitle, @articlebody, @writtenon)
.article
  .head {@title}
  .head {@subtitle}
  div(style='float:left;clear:both')
    .body
      {@articlecontent}
    .foot
      {@writtenon}
```

So, as you can see, I want this bunch of code to be parametrized so I can reuse it like this in my page:

```
doctype 5
html
  head
    title = title
  body
    .article('my first art', 'dummy subtitle', 'bla bla bla... lorem ipsum', '12/12/2012')
    .article('my second art', 'dummy subtitle', 'bla bla bla... lorem ipsum', '12/12/2012')
```

and so on...

Consider also that parameters might be long values. In my example, one of the parameters is the body of an article. I need to insert there the html code of the body

I searched the web in order to understand how to do this, but could not find any tutorial or valid example.

Can you help me please? Thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am unfamiliar with `ascx` files so I don't know if this is what you are thinking of, but there are different template engines that have been written for node.js that allow for reuse of frontend templates (html-like files). For example, in the [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) engine has [mixins](http://jade-lang.com/reference/#mixins) that allow you to pass parameters to a template.

Comment: OK, got it... nice thing... this answer is ok if you tell me how I can successfully import mixins from other files instead of writing mixins in the same file... is it possible? I am having quite a hard time to find the answer on the INet...

Comment: Max please forgive me, I have to take back the check on your answer. Please read again my question. I am sorry for this, but I managed to create simple mixins, but when trying to use parameters they did not work... Could you possibly write an example? Thankyou and sorry again.

Comment: Its ok, I'm not offended :). If my answer doesn't answer your question, then I don't want the 'accept'. After reading your updated question, I still think that Mixins (https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#mixins) provide exactly what you're looking for. Check out the example there again.

Comment: Yeah I read that, but I try to put string as a parameter and what I get is just errors... I am editing now the question in order to explain it better...

Comment: Ahhh... wait a sec... Mixins are translated into javascript? So I need to pass parameters, for example strings, using quotations, right?

Comment: Correct. You can pass identifiers (variables) and values such as numbers and strings. But in order for the parser to differentiate between identifiers and strings, you have to put quotes around strings.